# 100 off for any three product within category

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, opensource

I want to create the discount within the category.
**100 off for any three product within category**
[image]

[image]

But my rule apply only when user buy three item from the same product. Not within Category any three products

Comment: I have added my answer below. Please check and let me know if you have any query.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "Conditions" tab, try the cart rule conditions tab under "Actions". Like this:
[image]

Comment: Tried but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I Have checked on it. You should apply condition as per below screen shot. It will work when user buy three item from the same product as well as will work within Category any three products.

Please check screen shot:- https://prnt.sc/xsprwd